# Insert params into database as full object?

Tags: django, parameters, object, model, insert

un rails i can simply insert the params into the database with one command, when all form-field names are the same like the model-field names. is this possible in django as well, or do i have to set each param individually. i have like 20 fields, so it's a bit of a mess.. :)

something like:

```
blah = Contact()
blah.content = params[]
blah.save()
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're using a form, you should use a ModelForm, so you can do `form.save()`.

But generally, you can instantiate an object from a dictionary of parameters using the `**kwargs` format:

```
blah = Contact(**params)
```